Plus construction of the product spaces
I am newly learning plus construction in topology. My question is how to prove  the following:
The plus construction of the product of two CW complexes is homotopically  equivalent to the product of the plus construction of two spaces?
By the properties of plus construction i get a map from $(X_1 \times X_2)^+ $ to $X_1^+ \times X_2^+$ which gives isomorphism onto all homology groups. Now how to conclude this map is a homotopy equivalence? If these plus constructions are abelian space (i.e. $\pi_1$ acts trivially on $\pi_n$) then by whitehead theorem we are done. But I do not know does they are abelian or not!
Thanks in advance.

Presumably you perform plus constructions with respect to perfect subgroups $G_1\subseteq\pi_1(X_1)$, $G_2\subseteq\pi_1(X_2)$ and $G_1\times G_2\subseteq\pi_1(X_1)\times\pi_1(X_2)\cong\pi_1(X_1\times X_2)$?

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე yes.

The plus construction is a localization.

The plus construction $Y \rightarrow Y^+$ induces an isomorphism in homology with twisted coefficients in any $\pi_1(Y^+)$ module.
Let's use this in the case in hand. Let $ \Gamma_i = \pi_1(X_i^+)$. Since the natural map under $X_1 \times X_2$, $f: (X_1 \times X_2)^+ \rightarrow X_1^+ \times X_2^+$, induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$, it induces a $\Gamma_1 \times \Gamma_2$-equivariant map  $\tilde f$ on their simply connected covers.  But now the property stated above tells us that $\tilde f$ induces an isomorphism in homology, as its domain and range both have homology $H_*(X_1 \times X_2; \mathbb Z[\Gamma_1 \times \Gamma_2])$.
So $\tilde f$ is a homotopy equivalence, and thus so is $f$.
